# Find fundamental set of solutions for 2nd order ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to find the fundamental set of solutions ${y_1,y_2}$ for the equation $$y''-25ty'+25y=0$$ I am told that $y_1=t$ is a solution, how would I go about finding $y_2$, and if $y_1$ was not given, how could I find it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have one (nonzero) solution, you can find the others by Reduction of Order.  The basic idea is to write $y(t) = y_1(t) u(t)$ and plug it in to the differential equation.  You'll get an equation involving $u''$ and $u'$ (but not $u$ itself), which you can solve as 
a first-order linear equation in $v = u'$, then integrate to get $u$.

You might find [these notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/roo/roo.html) useful.

In general, solving second-order linear equations with non-constant coefficients is difficult, in fact in most cases there are no
closed-form solutions.  But if you suspect there is a solution that is a polynomial, it's often not hard to check whether that is the case and if so find the solution.

In this case, suppose there is a polynomial solution of degree $d$:
$y = a_d t^d + \ldots + a_0$ with $a_d \ne 0$.  Then $y'' - 25 t y' + 25 y$ would be 
a polynomial of degree $\le d$: its coefficient of $t^d$ would be
$- 25 d a_d + 25 a_d$.    But that must be $0$, so $d = 1$.  And then you check that the constant term is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$y=tu \\
y' = u + tu'\\
y'' = 2u'+tu''\\
y'' - 25ty'+25y = 2u' + tu''-25t^2u' = 0\\
tu'' +(2-25t^2)u' = 0\\
v= u'\\
tv' +(2-25t^2)v = 0$

And now you have a $1^{st}$ order diff eq.

I see a problem coming....
Finding v is easy enough.  But you are going to need to integrate v to find u, and v is not going to be easy to integrate (will not integrate into elementary functions).