# How to find a solution to a homogeneous ordinary differential equation with non-constant coefficients (the coefficients are linear functions)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I am trying to find a solution to a differential equation in the form
$$y'' + (ax+b)y' + (cx+d)y = 0,$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are constants. I only know how to solve when the coefficients are constants, and for the case of non-constant coefficients, I only know to solve when one of the solution is given. Is there any method for this kind of ODEs?

Comment: One of several ways to start would be to seek a series solution. From this there are often known series that would match certain combinations of the values of the constants.

Comment: start with some combination of that given solution, use change of variable and try reduce the order, or convert to equation of ode with constant terms.

Comment: Ref:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760103/find-fundamental-set-of-solutions-for-2nd-order-ode

Comment: The explicit solution is a quite horrible expression https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+y%27%27%28x%29%2B%28ax%2Bb%29y%E2%80%B2%28x%29%2B%28cx%2Bd%29y%28x%29%3D0+

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you substitute $y(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{4}ax^2-\frac{1}{2}bx}\,u(x)$ in the ODE, you will obtain the following differential equation for $u$:
$$
u''+(Ax^2+Bx+C)u=0, \tag{1}
$$
where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are functions of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. The solutions to $(1)$ are special functions known as [parabolic cylinder functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function).